# How to check if the cell is empty. c#/datagridview

Tags: c#, datagridview

I've got an event handler for a cell click. I want to check if the cell i click on contains something. If not then send a error message. In addition to this, i only want the user to be able to click on the first 2 columns, and if any other columns are clicked then it wont do anything. Any ideas?

```
FirstName   |   LastName   | Monday   | Tuesday   |   Wednesday  |
            |              |          |           |              |
William     |   Oliver     |          |           |              |
James       |   Price      |          |           |              |
```

So if the names are selected then it will do something. If the blank cells in Monday/Tuesday etc are clicked then nothing will happen.

Hope this makes sense.

code:

```
private void metroDataGrid1_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e) 
{
     //if Statement to see if cell contains anything, if it does then open a new form below...

    frmUserDiary userdiaryclick = new frmUserDiary();
    userdiaryclick.ShowDialog();
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Can you post a code snippet showing what you are trying to do

Comment: Post the code by editing your question not in the comments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are trying to achieve should be something like this

```
private void metroDataGrid1_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e) 
{

//IF Statement to see if cell contains anything, if it does then open a new form below...
         if (metroDataGrid1.CurrentCell != null && metroDataGrid1.CurrentCell.Value != null)
         {
             var cellValue = metroDataGrid1.CurrentCell.Value.ToString();
             frmUserDiary userdiaryclick = new frmUserDiary(); 
             userdiaryclick.ShowDialog();
         }
         else   
         { 
            // do something
         }

}
```

Comment: I'm getting an error message on this part of the code... (metroDataGrid1.CurrentCell.Value))      -  Cannot covert from 'object' to 'string'  Thanks :)

Comment: Does this answer your question?

Comment: null))  - there is an error here... "; or } expected"     Thanks

Comment: It was a typo, I have removed the extra )

Comment: The code you supplied still allows other cells to be clicked on if they have a value in them. I just want it where the first two columns can be clicked on and the form will appear. Any other cells after that will be ignored. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Updated code:

```
if (e.ColumnIndex == 0 || e.ColumnIndex == 1)
{
    frmUserDiary userdiaryclick = new frmUserDiary();
    userdiaryclick.ShowDialog();
}
```

I managed to figure the answer out. Thanks